# Show recurring local push notification in custom time interval

Tags: flutter

I want to show push notification to user in every 30 minutes but **Flutter Local Notification Plugin** has limitation that it supports the repeat intervals (EveryMinute, Hourly, Daily, Weekly).

What are the alternative that I can approach to?

Answer (score 0):

How about you use Timer and Flutter Local Notificaion Plugin like below?

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 30), () {
    // Make a local notification
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
    importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: 'item x');

});
```

Comment: This doesn't works when app is closed. How to handle that?